# How to use volume keys to open a activity when device is locked?

Tags: android

Hi all i want make app which run over volume key for example when we press the volume down key it turn camera open( when device is locked) similarly i want the same in my app.

Answer (score 3):

## I don't think that's possible

Those functionalities come from the factory OS you have, not from specific apps. The *only* way that could be possible is by rooting the device, in which case you may be able to listen to physical button clicks **and** modify their behaviour.

[This page](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/improve-functionality-android-power-button/) shows an application that can alter the buttons behaviour once the device is rooted, but again, this won't teach you how to do it, as again, it's not for the majority of the users and you'd need to root every device.

Comment: It may be possible because in vivo v3 mobile we can get touch after device locked. Like M for Play Music, W for open Whatsapp.

Comment: @Bansal as you see, you mentioned *one* device. This might be available because the OS Vivo runs is a custom tailored one. If you want to implement such gestures in an app, you may need a specific lib for that phone, and it won't be available for the rest. That being said. Ok, yeah, Anshul might be able to implement this, but he'd need to do so in so many different ways (close to one per device) that it's likely impossible be done, and you'd lose a general ecosystem (one device might need to have the power button clicked, while another needs to double tap the screen, etc).

Comment: @Abhishek as far as I know, those are events triggered not by buttons clicks, but by regular processes (daily tasks, location, whatever). The matter here is how to set the listener to expect for physical button clicks (which is not possible without root, according to what appears on that page I pasted)